# How can I read data from an Oracle SQL statement and pass it to other shell scripts?

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, bash, shell

Can anybody help me with how I would do something like this? I have a shell script and I want to select data from an oracle database and grab this into a variable, and from this variable run a script or scripts.

So lets say if one of the values from the query was, script2. Then I want it to use the other values from the select statement and pass it to be used in the script2.sh Shell script. Can we do something like this?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: So lets say. I have a shell script that outputs data from an oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your SQL statement in a file this way:

```
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
set echo off
spool output.txt
<your query>
spool off
```

Run the above file in your script this way:

```
sqlplus -s username/password < abovefilename.sql
```

Then the script can read from `output.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also bypass spooling like this (in bash):

```
max_salary=`sqlplus -s username/password@database <<END_SQL
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON 
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM emp;
END_SQL
`
echo $max_salary
```